Can i integrate prefectHQ workflow orchestrator with saltstack
I'm new to this tools, i'm using this tools for migration tool in networking. Can I integrate PrefectHQ with SaltStack?
I installed PrefecHq on VS code and understanding the basics of how flow, tasks and deployments works. And also gone through installation steps of SaltStack.But I'm not getting how to integrate this both. How it is going to help.

Saltstack has a REST API service, cald salt-api.
Send requests to that service from your workflow. Here is an entry point to the respective documentation, there are currently two backend types used, having similar interface: https://docs.saltproject.io/en/latest/ref/netapi/all/index.html
You can find an somewhat unsupported python client library as an implementation example here:
https://github.com/saltstack/pepper
With such information, you'd likely want to create wrappers for prefect tasks to hide some implementation detail in your actual workflows.

I installed Prefect on one VM (172.27.1.156) and set up the Salt Master and Minion on two other VMs. Is it necessary to install Salt on the VM where Prefect is running?
Thanks in advance

no, you don't need to have them running on the same machine when communication is done via REST API/salt-api.
